# Testing Perl module with Test::More (Intermediate Perl, chapter 14)

Tags: perl, testing, module

This is my first question to Stack Overflow.  Apologies in advance if I am breaking some rules.

I have been reading Chapter 14 of Intermediate Perl, 2nd ed., which discusses testing Perl modules and using features from Test::More.  I am referring to code published directly in this book in the Section titled "Adding Our First Tests".

For some background, in this chapter, a sample `Animal` class is created in a module with the same name.  This class has a simple `speak` method which looks like this:

```
sub speak {
    my $class = shift;
    print "a $class goes ", $class->sound, "!\n";
}
```

The `sound` method is a simple string returned for an particular Animal, so for example, a Horse's `sound` method will be simply `sub sound { "neigh" }` and it's `speak` method should output the following:

```
A Horse goes neigh!
```

The problem I'm running into is the following:  in the testing code I've created at ./Animal/t/Animal.t , I am instructed to use bare blocks and `Test::More::is` to test that the `speak` method is working.  The code looks like this in the test file:

```
[test code snip]
{
    package Foofle;
    use parent qw(Animal);

    sub sound { 'foof' }
    is( Foofle->speak, 
        "A Foofle goes foof!\n", 
        "An Animal subclass does the right thing"
    );
}
```

The test fails.  I ran all the Build commands, but when running "Build test", I get this failure for the Animal test:

```
Undefined subroutine &Foofle::is called at t/Animal.t line 28.
```

When I try to explicitly use `Test::More::is` instead of just plain `is`, the test still fails with the following message:

```
#   Failed test 'An Animal subclass does the right thing'
#   at t/Animal.t line 28.
#          got: '1'
#     expected: 'A Foofle goes foof!
# '
```

My methods appear to be defined exactly as I explained.  I think the first error is a scope issue because of the bare blocks, but not 100% sure.  The second error I am unsure about, because if I were to create a `Foofle` class as a child of `Animal` and called `speak` on it, I would not get a 1 response, but rather the expected output.

Would someone be able to help out on what I may be doing wrong?  For perhaps relevant software versions, I am using perl v5.16, Test::More v0.98, and Module::Starter v1.58.

Comment: a fine question, well formed and containing appropriate details. welcome to SO

Answer (score 5):

You've quite correctly explained the reason for the first error, and fixed it right (with specifying the correct package name). But you seem to miss the simple fact: `speak` method of Animal class does not `return` this `a $class goes...` string - it returns the result of printing it (which is `1`) instead!

See, this subroutine:

```
sub speak {
    my $class = shift;
    print "a $class goes ", $class->sound, "!\n";
}
```

... does not have an explicit `return` statement. In this case returned is the result of evaluating the latest invoked statement of the subroutine - i.e., result of evaluating `print something`, which [is](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) `1` (`true`, actually).

That's why the test fails. You can fix it either with testing for `1` (but that's too trivial, I suppose) or changing the method itself so it will return a string that it prints. For example:

```
sub speak {
    my $class = shift;
    my $statement = "a $class goes " . $class->sound . "!\n";
    print $statement;
    return $statement;
}
```

... and, frankly speaking, both approaches look a bit... fishy. The latter one, while obviously more complete, will not actually cover all the functionality of this `speak` method: it tests whether the statement was correct or not only, but not whether it was printed or not. )

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  I should be returning the string instead of printing it.  I have to double check, but I think this will qualify as errata for this book.

Answer (score 4):

You've already worked out that the problem with your call to `is` was that you were in the wrong package at the time you made the call.  Fully specifying the function name as you have done works, as does importing `is` into your namespace by saying

```
use Test::More;
```

somewhere in the package with the test.

The answer to the rest of your question lies in the difference between what you are testing and what you are doing.  What `speak` *does* is print, but when you ask `is(speak, ...)`, you are asking about what `speak` returns, which is unrelated to what it printed.  It is in fact the not-very-useful return value of `print`.

Since the purpose of `speak` is to print a particular string, a test for `speak` should test that it did in fact print a string and that it was the right string.  For the test to do that, though, you need some way to capture what was printed.

There are in fact a couple of ways to do that, from using `IO::File` to force you to specify a file handle to which to print to monkey patching a replacement for `print` into you class, but the following technique doesn't require any modification to the system under test to improve its testability.

The `select` built-in allows you to change where `print` prints.  The default output channel is `STDOUT`, though you should generally pretend you don't know that kind of thing.  Fortunately, you can also use `select` to discover the original file handle, though you should probably make sure you restore the default file handle (which is, after all, a global variable) even if your test dies for some reason.  So you need to manage exceptions.  And you need a file handle you can check the contents of and not necessarily actually print anything; `IO::Scalar` can help there.

With this approach, you wind up being able to test the original code with

```
package AnimalTest;
use IO::Scalar;

use Test::More tests => 1;
use Try::Tiny;

{
    package Foofle;
    use base qw(Animal);

    sub sound { 'foof' }
}

{
    my $original_FH = select;
    try {
        my $result;
        select IO::Scalar->new(\$result);

        Foofle->speak();
        is(
            $result, "A Foofle goes foof!\n",
            "An Animal subclass does the right thing"
        );
    } catch {
        die $_;
    } finally {
        select $original_FH;
    };
}
```

`Try::Tiny` is making sure you don't litter if `speak` happens to give the `Animal` an aneurysm, `print` is redirected to modify a scalar rather than actually print to the screen, and now the test fails for the right reason, to wit:  the strings have mismatched capitalization.

You'll notice that there is a lot of set up involved; this is because the system under test is not particularly well set up for testability and so we have to compensate.  In my own code, this is not the approach I would choose, I would instead opt to make the original code more testable.  Then for the testing, I monkey-patch (i.e., override one of the methods under test), often using [TMOE](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMockObject%3a%3aExtends).  This approach looks more like this:

[in Animal:]

```
sub speak {
    my $class = shift;
    $class->print("a $class goes ", $class->sound, "!\n");
}

sub print {
    my $class = shift;
    print @_;
}
```

[later:]

```
{
    package Foofle;
    use base qw(Animal);

    sub sound { 'foof' }

    sub print {
        my ($self, @text) = @_;

        return join '', @text;
    }

}

is(
    Foofle->speak(), "A Foofle goes foof!\n",
    "An Animal subclass does the right thing"
);
```

You'll notice that this looks a lot more like your original code.  The main difference is that instead of calling built-in `print` directly, `Animal` calls `$class->print`, which in turns calls built-in `print`.  The subclass `Foofle` then overrides that `print` method to return its arguments rather than printing them, which gives the testing code access to what *would* have been printed.

This approach is much cleaner than having to modify globals in order to figure out what is getting printed, but it does have two disadvantages:  It requires modifying the code under test to make it more testable, and it never actually tests whether printing happens.  It just tests that `print` was called with the right arguments.  It is therefore imperative that Animal::print be so trivial as to be obviously correct by inspection.

Comment: This answer wound up being longer than I had intended, since I found that I wanted to present both alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I'm imagining your code looks something like:

```
package SomeTest;   # if omitted, it's like saying "package main"
use Test::More;
...
{
    package Foofle;
    is( something, something_else );
}
```

The `use Test::More` statement will export some of the `Test::More`'s functions to the calling namespace, in this case `SomeTest` (or `main`). This means that functions will be defined for the symbols `main::is`, `main::ok`, `main::done_testing`, etc.

In the block that begins with `package Foofle`, you are now in the `Foofle` namespace, so now Perl will look for a function that corresponds to the symbol `Foofle::is`. It won't find one, so it will complain and exit.

One workaround is to import `Test::More` into `Foofle`'s namespace, too.

```
{
    package Foofle;
    use Test::More;
    is( something, something_else );
}
```

and another one is to use a fully qualified method name to call `is`:

```
{
    package Foofle;
    Test::More::is( something, something_else );
}
```